# Laravel Elixir Webpack Object Spread Transformation Error

Tags: php, gulp, webpack, laravel-elixir, laravel-5.3

Did anyone get the object spread operator working in Laravel Elixir? My `test.js` file:

```
let a = {
    b: 'c',
    d: 'e'
}

let f = {
    g: 'h',
    ...a
}

console.log(f)
```

And the `gulpfile.js` code:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(mix => {
    mix.webpack('test.js');
});
```

And the error:

```
...
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/WEBZ/html/works/<project>/resources/assets/js/test.js: Unexpected token (8:4)

   6 | let f = {
   7 |     g: 'h',
>  8 |     ...a
     |     ^
   9 | }
  10 |
  11 | console.log(f)

BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: D:/WEBZ/html/works/<project>/resources/assets/js/t.js: Unexpected token (8:4)

   6 | let f = {
   7 |     g: 'h',
>  8 |     ...a
     |     ^
   9 | }
  10 |
  11 | console.log(f)
...
```

Tried many thigs. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using external `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    "presets": [ 'stage-2' ],
                    "plugins": [ 'transform-object-rest-spread' ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'vue',
                query: {
                    "presets": [ 'stage-2' ],
                    "plugins": [ 'transform-object-rest-spread' ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Put this file in the root of your project. But before you go ahead and run `gulp` please install the `babel-preset-stage-2` preset package for `babel`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

Looks like this is not fully official yet but, you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: Also, you could completely do away with `webpack.config.js` and follow instructions [here](https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2) if you are using Vue JS ^2.0